# Maven dependencies size

Tags: java, maven, jar, htmlunit

I have faced with a little problem, I have added next dependency in my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
```

And my project enlarges from **330kb** to **12.1mb** . I know that HTMLUnit based on Apache Http Client that weights much, but maybe Maven has some feature to exclude libraries/packages that doesn't used in sources? (not manual excluding)

Comment: Other dependencies might be getting pulled in.  Granted, your code might not be calling every method which uses those other dependencies, but Maven doesn't know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How should Maven know that? You might using some kind of DI which is during runtime ? You can of course [exclude dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) if you know that they are not used...and of course handle the dependencies correct for their purpose as already mentioned to use `<scop>test</scope>` if it's something which is used only for testing.

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>sample.ProjectD</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-D</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a testing dependency, you can always add `<scope>test</scope>` to keep it from being packaged in your build.